# Can I update my app from higher iOS version required to lower iOS version required?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm an iOS developer. I have an app with deployment target iOS6. The app has been approved and is available in AppStore now. I just wonder if I can update my app with deployment target iOS5?

Comment: why not? AppStore won't prohibit you from adding new versions of your own app

Comment: Make sure you test the app on an actual device running iOS 5 first before considering changing the deployment target.  Simulator testing is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in a new update just change the development target to whatever you want, then upload the update. It is a very common practice.